# Cant run MySQL server

Tags: mysql, xampp

im using XAMPP on MACOS

here is my log file

```
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/folders/6h/0k9bd25j1kl4v_381tm0vykh0000gn/T/ibfDLofU' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2018-03-11 00:07:24 7fff9cde13c0  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-03-11 00:07:24 4813 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Hovhanness-iMac.local.pid ended
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log is autoexplained:

So first try to solve permissions here:

```
2018-03-11  0:07:24 140735825187776 [ERROR] mysqld: 
Can't create/write to file '/var/folders/6h/0k9bd25j1kl4v_381tm0vykh0000gn/T/ibfDLofU' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
```

For this ( and other like this use google )
i.e.

```
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
```

Using google I saw this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/379714/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb-mysql-ubuntu

Check the next
...

And so on